# Почему у меня не получается добавить данные из TextBox в Базу Данных

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DB db = new DB();

    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

    MySqlCommand Studentcommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT  INTO student VALUES (@id, @FIO, @Data.R, @Adres, @FIO.M, @FIO.O, @Telefon, @Telefon.R, @Klass)", db.getConnection());

    Studentcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", textBox1.Text);
    Studentcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("FIO", textBox2.Text);
    Studentcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Data.R", textBox3.Text);
    Studentcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Adres", textBox4.Text);
    Studentcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("FIO.M", textBox5.Text);
    Studentcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("FIO.O", textBox6.Text);
    Studentcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telefon", textBox7.Text);
    Studentcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telefon.R", textBox8.Text);
    Studentcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Klass", textBox9.Text);

    adapter.SelectCommand = Studentcommand;
}
```

Это обработчик на кнопке, но в БД ничего не добавляется, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
... = new MySqlCommand("INSERT  INTO
                        ^^^^^^

adapter.SelectCommand = ...
        ^^^^^^
```

---

```
//adapter.SelectCommand = Studentcommand;
Studentcommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: При добавлении команды .ExecuteScalar, после заполнения TextBox и нажатия на кнопку всё крашится

Comment: @AVIER Термин "все крашится" мне неизвестен.

Comment: Ошибка, с текстом "Ссылка на обьект не указывает на экземпляр обьекта."